# I want to click a button after a short delay after a tab gets focus

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want the `setTimeout` function to execute when I've selected[focused] the tab. I am using Mozilla (Greasemonkey).

Here's what I've tried:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           [udit]click stumble button on pages
// @namespace      uditeewd
// @include        http://www.stumbleupon.com/interest/*
// @include        http://www.stumbleupon.com/channel/*
// @include        http://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/*
// @exclude        http://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/*/likes/interest*
// @exclude        http://www.stumbleupon.com/interest/*/followers*
// @exclude        http://www.stumbleupon.com/channel/*/followers*
// @exclude        file:///*
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(function(ButtonClickAction) {
var stumbButt   = document.querySelector ("div.stumbler-card a.stumble-button");
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
stumbButt.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}, 0);

document.addEventListener ("onfocus", ButtonClickAction, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Break it down to steps:

1. You want a tab focus to start a timer.
2. You want the timer to click a button when the time comes.

Note that you need to define what node(s) constitute the "tab".  Your current code fires on focus for the whole page.

So, the code would be something like:

```js
var theTab  = document.querySelector (YOU NEED TO FIGURE THIS OUT, IT'S HIGHLY PAGE SPECIFIC);

theTab.addEventListener ("focus", FireClickDelay, true);

function FireClickDelay () {    
    setTimeout (ClickTheButton, 100);
}

function ClickTheButton () {    
    var stumbButt   = document.querySelector ("div.stumbler-card a.stumble-button");
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    stumbButt.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: what should i put as query ? example of page : http://www.stumbleupon.com/interest/Psychology

Comment: can i set it to execute on tabs of certain urls like tabs with url http://www.stumbleupon.com/interest/*

Comment: @adi - yelling "help pleasee eeeeeeeeeeee" at other users trying to help you and who haven't been back to visit the site since they answered isn't helping your case much. Please cease and decist from such badgering.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  When I visit stumbleupon, it does not have "tabs" as that term is usually defined. And there is only 1 "Stumble This" button, so it not obvious why you would want to auto-click it when something gets focus.  I answered the ***code*** question as best as can be, based on the question.  Perhaps if you added screenshots showing what you mean by "tab" and what the desired result is?...

Comment: You're welcome.  It looks like you've figured out your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           [udit]click stumble button on pages
// @namespace      uditeewd
// @include        http://www.stumbleupon.com/interest/*
// @include        http://www.stumbleupon.com/channel/*
// @include        http://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/*
// @exclude        http://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/*/likes/interest*
// @exclude        http://www.stumbleupon.com/interest/*/followers*
// @exclude        http://www.stumbleupon.com/channel/*/followers*
// @exclude        file:///*
// ==/UserScript==

window.onfocus = function() {
    setTimeout (ClickTheButton, 0);
};

function ClickTheButton () {    
    var stumbButt   = document.querySelector ("div.stumbler-card a.stumble-button");
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    stumbButt.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[window.onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onblur) and [window.onfocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onfocus) ?

```
(function(){
    var timer = null;
    var has_switched = false;

    window.onblur = function(){
      timer = settimeout(changeitup, 2000);
    }  

    window.onfocus = function(){
      if(timer) cleartimeout(timer);
    }

    function changeitup(){
        if( has_switched == false ){
            alert('hey! who switched tabs?')
            has_switched = true;    
        }
    }
})();
```